# enviroment variables on jenkins pipeline for user and password

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, credentials

I´m quite new on using groovy for jenkins pipeline. I have a pipeline that is already running performing some steps like running unitest, sonnarqube anaysis etc. One of the steps is to upload artifact to artifactory using curl -u. I don´t want to show user and pass on output script, so I´m using credential plug in In which I stored user and password and has the ID. But I don´t know how to pass that to the sh command using variables. This is what I have now in that step using withCredentials .

```
stage ('Upload war to Artifactory') {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '7c9e8186-1f16-4920-837b-b571ea88a7e8', usernameVariable: 'willy11', passwordVariable: 'hello123')])
sh "sudo curl -u ${willy11}:{$hello123} -T $warPath 'https://artifactory.xxxxx.com:443/artifactory/Platform/$warFile'"
```

I don´t know how to pass or define values of **usernameVariable** and **passwordVariable** to use on the curl command. The way it is now, I get on output script:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: **There is no body to invoke**
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsStepContext.newBodyInvoker(CpsStepContext.java:283)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsStepContext.newBodyInvoker(CpsStepContext.java:95)
```

[image]

How can I achieve this? the credential plug in,  I read that supposedly puts *** on the output of the script, is this how this work? should I declare "will11" and "hello123"  elsewere and use as env variables?

Thank you.

```
def call(body) {

def config = [:]
body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
body.delegate = config
body()

def artifactName = 'extractor'
def artifactExt = '.war'
def artifactVersion = '0.0.1'

def buildPath = 'target/'
def warFile = artifactName + '-' + artifactVersion + artifactExt
def warPath = buildPath + warFile
def warNoVersion = artifactName + artifactExt

def deployPath = '/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/'
def deployFile = deployPath + warNoVersion

node {
    // Clean workspace before doing anything
    //deleteDir()

    try {

        stage ('Code Checkout') {
            git branch: 'master',
                credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                url: 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxctor'
        }


stage ('Configure Application') {
            configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: config.confiFileId, variable: 'CONFIG_FILE_PATH')]) {
                sh 'cp $CONFIG_FILE_PATH resources/config.properties'
            }
            sh "echo 'job_name: $JOB_NAME' > WebContent/version.txt"
            sh "echo 'job_number: $BUILD_NUMBER' >> WebContent/version.txt"
        }

        stage ('Run Unitests') {
            sh 'mvn test'
        }

        /*stage ('SonarQube analysis') {
          withSonarQubeEnv('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) {
            sh 'mvn sonar:sonar'
          }  
        }*/

        stage ('Compile and Build WAR') {
            sh 'mvn clean compile war:war'
        }

        stage ('Upload war to Artifactory') {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '7c9e8186-1f16-4920-837b-b571ea88a7e8', usernameVariable: 'USER', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')])
            sh "sudo curl -u ${USER}:{$PASSWORD} -T $warPath 'https://artifactory.xxxxxxx.com:443/artifactory/Platform/$warFile'" 

        }




    } catch (err) {
        notifyBuild('FAILURE', config.slackChannel)
        throw err
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the credentials binding plugin the credentials will be bound to environment variables and the code to be executed must be inside the curly braces of the withCredentials statement, this is what we've missed.

So use:

```
 stage ('Upload war to Artifactory') {
       withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '7c9e8186-1f16-4920-837b-b571ea88a7e8', usernameVariable: 'USER', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
           sh ("sudo curl -u $USER:$PASSWORD -T $warPath 'https://artifactory.xxxxx.com:443/artifactory/Platform/$warFile'")
       }
 }
```

instead of:

```
 stage ('Upload war to Artifactory') {
     withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '7c9e8186-1f16-4920-837b-b571ea88a7e8', usernameVariable: 'USER', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')])
         sh "sudo curl -u ${USER}:{$PASSWORD} -T $warPath 'https://artifactory.xxxxxxx.com:443/artifactory/Platform/$warFile'" 

 }
```

Comment: that´s what I also want to Know. where and how do I define the real USER and PASSWORD values inside the script? "willy11" "start123" I created them in jenkins globar variables. Will they be taken from there?

Comment: The values williy11 and start123 must be defined in the credential you are referencing ('7c9e8186-1f16-4920-837b-b571ea88a7e8').
The  usernameVariable: 'USER' will make the value of username of the credential available as  $USER, then you can use the $USER variable in curl or other command.

Comment: is strange, is til saying "java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no body to invoke" are you sure is USER and PASS the variables to use? I already set credentials on cred ID

Comment: It seems like is another point of failure, not the curl command, could you provide more information of your pipeline script?

Comment: I added the script. All steps are executed successfully in pipeline till the part that I want to upload to artifactory the war. If I just do Curl -u "realuser":"realpass" artifact gets uploaded successfully, but I don´t want to hardcode and to show it.

Comment: I updated my answer, I think it will solve the problem.